# Stored NSFetchRequest returns error "A fetch request must have an entity"

Tags: core-data, nsfetchrequest, fetched-property

I added a fetched property to my entity at data model. I did not add its predicate. I retrieve it with fetchRequestTemplateForName, but when execute it I got this error "executeFetchRequest:error: A fetch request must have an entity."

But how come I get this error. Isn't that fetched property a property of my entity ?

So I further debug the issue and find that it was because the retrieved NSFetchRequest == nil

[[self managedObjectModel] fetchRequestTemplateForName:@"somename"];

So how do I fix it ?

Thanks!

Qiu

Comment: on a fetchrequest object you should set an entity, may that is the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for answering my question. I added predicate as you suggested but NSFetchRequest still returned nil. Then I suddenly realized that I actually added **Fetched Property** NOT **Fetch Request** to my entity and that's the reason fetchRequestTemplateForName return nil. So I add Fetch Request (in Editor menu there are "Add Fetch Request" and "Add Fetched Property" menu items) and that fixed the problem! So sorry for the confusion :$.

But my question then is why we need fetched property as we already have fetch request ? I know apple document said something like "Fetched properties represent weak, one-way relationships."  But I still feel confused b/c fetch request seems more straightforward.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you created your fetched property in the Xcode model editor and not programmatically.  You need to fill out the predicate, otherwise there is nothing to fetch. Therefore, the `NSFetchRequest` comes back as `nil`.

A fetched property is really just a handy shortcut for writing out long-winded fetch requests in code time and again for results you do not want to persist. Maybe it is a good process to first see if your `NSFetchRequest` written in code works, and then transfer it to the model.